# Difference between ViewsLastMonths1, ViewsLastMonths2 and ViewsLastMonths3

Tags: web-part, analytics

I'm working with the `popularity trends web part` and would like to display the number of visits/unique users per item. As of right now I have `ViewsLastMonths1` and `ViewsLastMonths1Unique` displayed. However, I noticed there are also `ViewsLastMonths2` and `ViewsLastMonths3` available.

Is it safe to say that `ViewsLastMonths2` will show the last two months visits and `ViewsLastMonths3` will show the last three months visits?

Does anyone know the difference between these numbers and how they are generated?

Is it based on calendar month or the past 30, 60 or 90 days?

Comment: This resource has some information on the usage related properties. Hope this is helpful.
https://timeisnet.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/sharepoint-search-get-usage-data-from-search/

Answer (score 2):

ViewsLastMonths1, ViewsLastMonths2 and ViewsLastMonths3 depend upon what is the LastAnalyticsUpdateTime.

So if LastAnalyticsUpdateTime is 9 May 2019 then ViewslastMonths1 will have views for the month of May 2019, ViewsLastMonths2 will have views for month of April 2019 and ViewsLastMonths3 will have views for the Month of March 2019.